# Cannot install shutter due to libxml-simple-perl

Tags: apt, shutter

I cannot install shutter:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f  shutter                                                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shutter : Depends: libxml-simple-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt-get install -f libxml-simple-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxml-simple-perl : Depends: libxml-sax-perl but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libxml-libxml-perl but it is not going to be installed or
                               libxml-sax-expat-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS - "Wubuntu" standard install.
I have not added any other repositories.

Running: `apt-cache policy shutter libxml-simple-perl libxml-sax-perl libxml-libxml-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl` results in:

```
Installed: (none) and 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

for each of those packages.

What to do next?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy shutter libxml-simple-perl libxml-sax-perl libxml-libxml-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl`?

Comment: Edited with version.

Comment: @Braiam `Installed: (none)` and `500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages` for each of those packages.

Comment: Err, why not editing your question?

Comment: This looks like there might be a proxy blocking something?

Comment: No proxy. This is at home.

Comment: Tried adding `precise main universe` to `sources.list`. No go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding mirrors to my sources configuration:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install -f`

and shutter is installed.