# Cannot Install shutter

Tags: 12.04, shutter

I get this error when I try installing shutter:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f shutter 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shutter : Depends: libxml-simple-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I checked out the other [Ask Ubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385515/cannot-install-shutter-due-to-libxml-simple-perl) but the solution mentions mirrors but he has not elaborated further.

Comment: How did you install shutter?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install shutter`. Though, after your answer, I added the PPA and tried the software center too but it did not fix it.

Comment: see this question for how you can solve unmet dependencies, http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/10698

Comment: I suspect it has to to with the software ppa too - In my case, it says "NOT going to be installed" - I have only allowed important updates and no recommended updates. Is that causing this?

Comment: install all updates and try again...

Answer (score 1):

According to [shutters website](http://shutter-project.org/downloads/) it should be as simple as following the steps there.

1. Add the PPA with, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa`
2. update your source list with, `sudo apt-get update`.
3. And install shutter with `sudo apt-get install shutter`.

When I installed shutter on my 13.04/13.10 I just used the software center.

does this work for you?

Comment: I added the PPA and even then I get the same error. If I use the software center, I get an error saying that package has unmet dependencies...

Comment: what happens if you type `sudo apt-get install -f shutter` ?

Comment: Same error. I have updated the question with the full error message, if that helps.

Comment: @callmekatootie, have you solved out the issue ? I am also facing the same error messages. Even worse in mine case

Comment: @Gurjit Its many years back. I don't remember it but most likely I solved it my installing the dependencies myself manually. I say so because I have used Shutter every time and don't remember using anything else.

Comment: @callmekatootie, thanks so much for replying, actually I have to add a question here myself and it gets sorted. It's here http://askubuntu.com/questions/894639/shutter-is-not-getting-installed-in-ubuntu-16-04-due-to-unmet-dependencies/894820#894820