# Shutter is not getting installed in Ubuntu 16.04 due to unmet dependencies

Tags: 16.04, apt

I tried to install the **Shutter** in **Ubuntu 16.04** following these 3 commands

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install shutter

After running the **step 2** i.e **sudo apt-get update** my output is this :

```
Ign:1 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                    
Ign:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                                                                                   
Ign:5 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 Release                                              
Hit:9 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial InRelease                                                           
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                 
Hit:11 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise Release                                                           
Hit:12 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release                                                               
Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                                   
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rvm/smplayer/ubuntu xenial InRelease      
Hit:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease     
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease [55.7 kB]
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Hit:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease    
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release                
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
Hit:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Fetched 55.7 kB in 3s (14.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key C47415DFF48C09645B78609416126D3A3E5C1192 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Output from the **step 3** i.e **sudo apt-get install shutter** I am getting

```
 Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     shutter : Depends: gnome-web-photo but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgnome2-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgnome2-vfs-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgnome2-wnck-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgoo-canvas-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgtk2-appindicator-perl but it is not installable
               Depends: libgtk2-imageview-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgtk2-trayicon-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgtk2-unique-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libnet-oauth-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libproc-processtable-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libjson-xs-perl but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

In order to solve the `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
I tried this

- [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages).
- [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

No success till now. Any help is appreciated.

P.S After checking my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I found each link such that it mentions the `precise` in it.

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe mul$
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe$

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted unive$
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted univer$
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted univ$
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted u$
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted un$
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted $

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
```

Comment: Why do you have precise (12.04) repositories enabled on a xenial (16.04) installation? Open your System Settings > Software & Updates and disable everything mentioning "precise". After that, try again (`sudo apt update ; sudo apt install shutter`).

Comment: @ByteCommander , thanks mate for the help. I will check and let you know

Comment: Try: `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: @George done , `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: @ByteCommander, there was 2 mentions of the `precise` in the Software & Updates > Other Softwares . I disabled them. Still the output is same. Any other thing please let me know

Comment: @George, if you have any other hints let me know please.

Comment: I see a lot precise repo in your update output that might be the issue!

Comment: @George, I have disabled those already.

Comment: please run `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: @George done , ` Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`

Comment: Now `update` and do `dist-upgrade` then try install shutter

Comment: @George, I don't want `dist-upgrade` can lead to other issues.I tried with the update, though it again gives me precise again too.

Comment: @George, I tried removing every mention of the precise from the system settings. Any other way I can edit it. Thanks

Comment: @George, I checked my `/etc/apt/sources.list` strangely I found each link has mention of `precise` there ? Is it normal to have. I have updated the question too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55655/discussion-between-gurjit-and-george).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the hints from @George, I was able to finally install **shutter**. I disabled all the repositories in the list mentioning **precise**. Surprisingly every repository has mention of it, replaced it with the following list

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then again try the `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install shutter` to successfully install it.

Comment: Great it worked out. Had to attend to  my kids sorry for the absence. You should not be having `precise` with `xenial` to be on the safe side... :).

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen thanks it wouldn't be possible without your inputs